Set Interior.Color of Range to Interior.Color of another Range of the same size
i am working on a sort of graphics api in Excel, where i need to display textures.
I am displaying them as a range, where the cells are painted. To display it i need to set the interior.color of each cell of range1 to the interior.color of each cell of range2. The simple solution would be a for each loop but im trying to get it to a oneliner for performance reasons.
The code is:
Public Sub Initialize(ByVal WorkbookName As String, ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal n_SheetRow As Long, ByVal n_SheetColumn As Long, ByVal n_LastRow As Long, ByVal n_LastColumn As Long)
    Dim TextureSheet As Range
    p_SheetRow = n_SheetRow
    p_SheetColumn = n_SheetColumn
    p_LastRow = n_LastRow
    p_LastColumn = n_LastColumn
    Set TextureSheet = Workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1")
1.  Set p_OriginalTexture = Range(TextureSheet.Offset(p_SheetRow, p_SheetColumn), TextureSheet.Offset(p_SheetRow + p_LastRow, p_SheetColumn + p_LastColumn))
2.  p_OriginalTexture.Interior.Color = Range(TextureSheet.Offset(p_SheetRow, p_SheetColumn), TextureSheet.Offset(p_SheetRow + p_LastRow, p_SheetColumn + p_LastColumn)).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    p_OriginalTexture.Select
    Set p_Texture = p_OriginalTexture.Offset(p_LastRow + 1, 0)
    p_Texture.Interior.Color = p_OriginalTexture.Interior.Color
    p_Initialized = True
End Sub

Upper cell block SHOULD be the texture and it SHOULD paste these colors to the black block
SheetRow, SheetColumn, LastRow and LastColumn are properties of the Texture-class and are used to describe the position and size of the texture.
p_OriginalTexture is set once in initialization.
p_Texture is the one being used as texture later on.

was my first idea. Doing this changed all the cells in p_Texture to black
was my second idea. Doing this changed all the cells in p_Texture to black too


How about something like selecting the source range as above and then:
Selection.Copy
Range("destination_range").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

That should move just the textures and colours from the source range to the destination. And you can dispose of the first "Select" verb as well. ie
Range("source_range").Copy


That would probably work but i would need it in form of the p_Texture variable, because there are other classes who are dependent on that data. For example rotation/translation/scaling/cutting functions who change the data to fit it into the "screen". For some reason it works if i hard code the colorvalue but that would be really tedious with larger amounts of textures. Do you know how the DisplayFormat.Interior.Color is different from just using Interior.Color?

That aspect of Excel is like the "maze or twisty little passages all alike" in Zork. Some things will work OK and most will not. If given an inconsistent request or something it can't do Excel tends to replace the entire lot with black cat in a coal cellar as you have found. I don't really see why you can't repaint the texture and colours this way since it is self contained. Your alternative is to very tediously set every cell in the range in a loop. It is a real mess when cells have different characteristics like this.

OK set the p_texture global variable after you have overpainted the display format settings onto the target range then. The cell texture and colour interactions are best described as peculiar when you have complex different patterns applied cell by cell and/or conditional formats acting on the same ranges.


rng1.Interior.Color = rng2.Interior.Color may not produce the expected result due to variations in filling color within the source range.
If all cells within the source range have the same color, the code will work as intended.
However, if there are variations in color, the target range may end up filled with the color black.
Perhaps the answer from @Martin Brown is an option to avoid looping in this scenario.

Sub Demo()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngC As Range
    Set rngC = Range("C1:C3")
    Debug.Print rngC.Interior.Color ' output is 255 (vbRed)
    rngC.Offset(5).Interior.Color = rngC.Interior.Color
    Set rngA = Range("A1:A3")
    Debug.Print rngA.Interior.Color ' output is 0 
    rngA.Offset(5).Interior.Color = rngA.Interior.Color ' vbBlack = 0
End Sub



Your code is quite confusing and the image is not very readable (no reference to the code). But maybe you can try to adapt code that uses the Value(11) property, which is Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet).
This is probably slower than the usual Copy-Paste copying, but it allows you to assign range properties directly to another range. The target range can be smaller than the source, but it can't be larger.
Sub CopyTexture()
    Dim Src As Range, Dest As Range
    Set Src = Range("D4:E6")
    Set Dest = Range("D9").Resize(Src.Rows.Count, Src.Columns.Count)
    Dest.Value(11) = Src.Value(11)
End Sub


